# what is the asymptotic distribution of kurtosis?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, kurtosis

i am going to do a Monet Carlo simulation to calculate the p value of kurtosis test statistic. For that i need the asymptotic distribution. I know that is normal distribution. But i dont know the parameters. 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you asking about the asymptotic distribution of sample kurtosis when sampling from a normal distribution? Or more generally? Also, which formula for sample kurtosis are you using? There's more than one definition of sample kurtosis. ... Joanes and Gill give bias and standard error for various definitions ... [Joanes, D. N. and Gill, C. A. (1998), “Comparing Measures of Sample Skewness and Kurtosis,” *The Statistician*, 47, Part 1, pp. 183-189]

Comment: "Monet Carlo" simulations must be the work of the [Impressionist school of statistics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Monet).

Comment: my starting point to references when the underlying distribution is not assumed to be the normal distribution: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8274